# Error on Recordset update after addnew saying a column cannot be null even with a default set to empty string

Tags: mysql, vb6, odbc, ado

I've got a program that i've been supporting that recently was installed on a windows 7 machine.  Everything has been working however recently this machine has started Receiving the following error when using the recordset.update method after modifying fields i've received the following error.

> -2147467259 ([MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-4.0.18-nt]Column 'fd_number' cannot be null)

The table 'fd_number' is in looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `bookguide` (
`author` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
`title` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
`isbn` varchar(13) NOT NULL default '',
`whls` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL default '0.0000',
`oldwhls` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL default '0.0000',
`fd_number` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
KEY `isbn` (`isbn`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

The code that modifies this table looks like this:

```
780     Do While Not txtstream.AtEndOfStream
790         Line = txtstream.ReadLine

800         rs.addNew
            'tempwhole = Mid$(line, 2, 9) + Mid$(line, 119, 1)
810         author = Mid$(Line, 10, 15)
820         author = Replace(author, "'", "")
830         author = Replace(author, ",", "")
840         title = Mid$(Line, 25, 70)
850         title = Replace(title, "'", "")
860         title = Replace(title, ",", "")
            'tempisbn = Mid$(tempwhole, 2, 8)
870         rs.fields("isbn").Value = Replace(Trim$(Mid$(Line, 95, 13)), "-", "")
880         rs.fields("author").Value = author
890        rs.fields("title").Value = title
900        rs.fields("whls").Value = Val(Mid$(Line, 139, 5))    
910        rs.Update
920    Loop
```

This is just one example of where this is failing, There are most likely thousands of updates/inserts done this way through out the entire program.

I've attempted to reinstall of MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver (3.51.27) several times, including using an older version (3.51.06), which takes away the ADO problem but introduces an error that says something to the effect of *ODBC Driver does not support the requested Properties* on this section of code right after the above loop.

```
940    rs.Open "UPDATE bookguide SET oldwhls = whls, whls = 0",conn
```

Comment: So after adding a procedure that loops through the recordset and assigns empty strings to the object's columns, I end up with the same error that ODBC 3.51.06 Driver gave me.  I've never had to split the update statement before but I'm thinking of trying that in the hopes that it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue it seems to be was that the multiple versions of the ODBC driver, the uninstalls for the the newer one/old one still seemed to leave the dlls and lib files in sysWOW64, Once I uninstalled both version of myODBC and removed the files from the sysWOW64 directory and reinstalled the 3.51.27 driver the error has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your default value of `''` is not being applied on that field. Have you tried the [MySQL ODBC driver 5.1.7](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html) ?

Comment: Well that'd work if it supported the DB's version of 4.0.18 unfortunately it only works with 4.1.1 or higher. I guess I might need to upgrade the DB to get it to work.

Comment: After Upgrading the Server to the latest mysql Version I'm still getting the error using ODBC Connector 5.1

Comment: try setting the value before calling rs.update i.e.  rs.fields("fd_number") = ""

Comment: I've added that but unfortunately it's getting to the next Statement line 940 up above and then giving me the "ODBC Driver does not support the requested Properties" when it tries to execute that. I've already tried changing that to conn.execute Instead of rs.open and received the same result.

Comment: Have you closing the recordset object before trying to reuse it? i.e. rs.close set rs=new adodb.recordset rs.open ""

Comment: This same code works on every other machine I've tried it on including other windows 7 x64 that are in the exact same configuration, And the recordset is closed before it is used again. Line 930 reads rs.close

Comment: Have you tried running the component checker on the two computers to compare the difference? If it works on one computer and not the other, you need to find what is different. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=8f0a8df6-4a21-4b43-bf53-14332ef092c9&displaylang=en and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810805.aspx